# DROP temporary table gives 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]

Tags: php, sql, pdo, mariadb

I trying to import csv file into database. Without $daco3 its working, but only once, I delete values in database table run php script, it imports values from csv. I add one more line into csv file. Run this php script and nothing happens. I need to delete values again. So I need to drop temp table, so it will import values again, but without success. Code is below. (After that I want to add WHERE clause in $daco2, so it is not going to import save values again, but for this moment I am totally fine with that)

```
if(!file_exists($csvfile)) {
die("File not found. Make sure you specified the correct path.");
}

try {
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$databasehost;dbname=$databasename", 
    $databaseusername, $databasepassword,
    array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true
    )
);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
die("database connection failed: ".$e->getMessage());
}


$affectedRows = $pdo->exec("
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_table4 LIKE ports");


$daco = $pdo->exec("
  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ".$pdo->quote($csvfile)." INTO TABLE `$temp`
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($fieldseparator)."
  LINES TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($lineseparator)); 

$daco2 = $pdo->exec("
  SHOW COLUMNS FROM `$databasetable`;
  INSERT INTO `$databasetable`
  SELECT * FROM `$temp` ");

$daco3 = $pdo->exec("DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temporary_table");
```

Which gives me

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.' in C:\test\csv.php:48

Line 48 is $daco3. And I don't get it, I already set PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.
Do you know, where I made mistake?

Thanks

Comment: What's the point of running `SHOW COLUMNS FROM $databasetable` query?

Comment: what's the point of using a temporary table at all?

Comment: I need to use temporary table. I want to use WHERE NOT EXISTS (something like  temp.name=dbtable.name). And you can't use this simply in LOAD data local..first you need to import this data to temporary table and then compare results when adding them into real table.

Comment: ok, first question then

Comment: I found this solution in different thread..and it was working, so I wasn't asking myself if it is necesarry

Comment: Well just get rid of this useless query

Comment: I done it and update it to `SELECT * FROM  $temp LEFT JOIN ports ON temporary_table4.id = ports.id WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ports.id FROM ports where temporary_table4.id = ports.id)");` , but it gives me _Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1_

Comment: that's a different question. and here is not a forum. you cannot sit here all day long asking to fix every mistake you made. what it this join here for?

Comment: At first I asked why it gives PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, when it was already set. And it leads to this, but no worries it is working now. **THANKS**